# Java Servlet supports POST, but form returns an error anyhow

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a form that calls the post method in a servlet.  I keep getting the "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" error, but I have been staring at it for a long time now and I can't see what is wrong.  I have overidden the doPost method.

This is the form from my JSP

```html
<%-- View all Users Section --%>
<div class="generalDisplay" id="AllUsers">
    <table class="generalTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>User Power</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${AllUsers}"  varStatus="loopStatus">
        <form method="post" action="UserEditServlet">
            <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? '' : 'alt'}" id="${user.userName}">
                <td>${user.userName}<input type="hidden" value="${user.userName}" name="userName" /></td>
                <td><input class="hidableButton" disabled type="text" name="FirstName" value="${user.firstName}"</td>
                <td><input class="hidableButton" disabled type="text" name="LastName" value="${user.lastName}"</td>
                <td><input class="hidableButton" disabled type="text" name="UserPower" value="${user.userPower}"</td>
                <td class="buttonColumn"><button type="button" id="EditChangesButton" class="openInputFields">Edit User</button></td>
                <td class="buttonColumn"><button class="hidableButton" disabled id="SaveChangesButton" type="submit">Save Changes</button></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my Servlet

```
package cellar.servlets;

import cellar.models.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class UserEditServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //  Checks for user first
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("User");
    if((user != null) && (user.getUserPower() == 1 ))  {
        // user loged in, so continue
        User UserChanged = new User();
            UserChanged.setUserFromDB(request.getParameter("userName").toUpperCase());
        UserChanged.changeThisUser(request.getParameter("FirstName"), request.getParameter("LastName"), Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("UserPower")));
        String url = "/RefreshAdminMenu";
            getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
        }
    }

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url = "/index.jsp";
            getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

And here is the pertinent lines from my web.xml

```
<session-config>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserEditServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>cellar.servlets.UserEditServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserEditServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UserEditServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</session-config>
```

Any input you can help would be great.  I am struggling with this today.  This app is fairly large now and this is the only function that isn't working.  I have a similar screen to edit another DB object and it works fine.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar before submitting the form? What is it after you have submitted the form? Are you sure you recompiled and redeployed your webapp.

Comment: Before, it read "RefreshAdminMenu", which is the servlet that takes me to the menu.  After it read "UserEditServlet".  I have been getting this error in a development environment using Netbeans and Tomcat7.  I rechecked that the app was undeployeed and it kept doing it.  I went ahead and rebuilt a new instance of Tomcat7, and it works fine now.  Any guess what went wrong there?